# Does Kafka broker send ACK for each message or for each message batch?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using Kafka 0.8.2. As the document says:

**batch.num.messages** specifies:

The number of messages to send in one batch when using async mode. The producer will wait until either this number of messages are ready to send or queue.buffer.max.ms is reached.

and **request.required.acks** controls broker acknowledgement of requests.

I wonder how does Kafka broker send this acknowledgement, does it send ACK for the batch, or for each individual message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.slideshare.net/miguno/apache-kafka-08-basic-training-verisign (slide 83):

> The original list of messages is partitioned (randomly if the default
>   partitioner is used) based on their destination partitions/topics,
>   i.e. split into smaller batches. Each post-split batch is sent to the
>   respective leader broker/ISR (the individual send()’s happen
>   sequentially), and each is acked by its respective leader broker
>   according to request.required.acks